# Count on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get an output from table of fields A, B, C to display

```
A | Count(A)
```

where the number of rows = distinct instances of A and the sum of the values for count(A) equals total number of rows in the database?

Comment: I think you'll get a more accurate response to your question if you include a sample dataset and if possible the expected output from that sample dataset.  It doesn't need to be a big sample, something like 4-10 rows is usually enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT A, COUNT(1) FROM your_table_name GROUP BY A;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DISTINCT keyword inside the COUNT

Like this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like AI mentioned a dataset and the final outcome would be helpful. From the small example you gave, i think this might be what you are looking for

SELECT Field_A, Count(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY Field_A
UNION ALL
SELECT Field_B, Count(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY Field_B
UNION ALL
SELECT Field_C, Count(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY Field_C

The output for that would be something similiar to depending on how many unique values you have in Field_A, Field_B, Field_C

Value_In_A1 - 10
Value_In_A2 - 11
Value_In_A3 - 15
Value_In_A4 - 8
Value_In_B1 - 9
Value_In_C1 - 25
Value_In_C2 - 2